# @media function not working in this CSS code

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to make the @media work with this webpage, but have been unable to do so. I have the follow CSS and HTML code plugged in. What am I missing? When I try to resize the page the new style for the appropriate pixel does not take effect. However, the min-width: 1281px style does indeed work. The ones below it does not work

Tried on multiple different browsers, and did research online. Seems like the code is correct, not sure what am I missing.

```
@media (min-width: 1281px){
{CSS STYLES-1}
    }
@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px){
{CSS STYLES-2}
    }
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
{CSS STYLES-3}
    }
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
{CSS STYLES-4}
    }
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
{CSS STYLES-5}
    }
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
{CSS STYLES-6}
    }

     <meta charset="utf-8" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
{HTML CODE}
```

when the window size is decreased I would like the CSS style e to change to match accordingly. I am mainly concern about mobile devices, tablets, laptop screens, and desktop, etc

Comment: Can you recreate it in a jsfiddle or something similar? Also I'm guessing you just omitted this for brevity in the above, but is your CSS definitely being wrapped or imported in a `<style>` tag?

Comment: Make sure to have something like this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your `<head>` section

Comment: @sean can you provide a bit more code?

Comment: @UpQuark the CSS is on a separate file that is called using reference link syntax. Never heard of JSFIDDLE, looking into this now.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith yes, I have this within header section.

Comment: @Aditya I have a lot of code and cascading involved. What would you like me to send?

Comment: @Sean can you update your question with your HTML? Currently, your CSS is working https://jsfiddle.net/xrb68g30/

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I'm on code pen. Username is stevenson-gerard. Can you take a look there please? Problem is when I adjust the screen from one pixel media to another pixel media, I notice the changes does not take affect. Example, from full screen, to smaller screen size, the appropriate CSS changes does not take affect.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the order that I placed the @media? I reorder from least to greatest, and it gave me a different result. Still not the resolution though.